# How can I access array's elements with a foreach?

Tags: perl

This my array in Perl:

```
@test = ("user1","user1val1","user1val2","user3val1","user2","user2val1","user2val2","user2val3");
```

How can I access elements with a foreach? The one I test doesn't work:

```
foreach my $dataLine(@test)
{
    print $dataLine[0];
}
```

I want to access the values "user1" and "user2".

Answer (score 2):

`$dataLine` is a scalar, so no `[0]` index:

```
for my $dataLine (@test)
{
    print $dataLine, "\n";
}
```

If you only want to access the ones on positions 0, 4, etc., you can use

```
for my $dataline (@test[ grep 0 == $_ % 4, 0 .. $#test ])
{
    print $dataline, "\n";
}
```

It uses the modulo operator `%`, `$#test` is the index of the last element in `@test`.

Or, if you want to exclude elements with `val` in them:

```
for my $dataline (grep ! /val/, @test) {
    print "$dataline\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear if you actually want/need to be using a list. Looking at your data it looks like you might want to be using a hash keyed by user pointing at a list of user values. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my %test = (
    "user1" => ["user1val1", "user1val2"],
    "user2" => ["user2val1", "user2val2", "user2val3"],
    "user3" => ["user3val1"],
);

foreach my $user (sort keys %test) {
    print("$user:\n");
    foreach my $user_value (sort @{$test{$user}}) {
        print "    $user_value\n"
    }   
}
```

Which will output the following:

```
$ ./test.pl 
user1:
    user1val1
    user1val2
user2:
    user2val1
    user2val2
    user2val3
user3:
    user3val1
```

Note that the user list is an array ref not an array. Personally I would use a hash ref as well like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $test = {
    user1 => [ qw(user1val1 user1val2) ],
    user2 => [ qw(user2val1 user2val2 user2val3)],
    user3 => [ qw(user3val1)],
};

foreach my $user (sort keys %{$test}) {
    print("$user:\n");
    foreach my $user_value (sort @{$test->{$user}}) {
        print "    $user_value\n"
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering me. I get the data from mysql from a module with a select (ex: idUser, Username, userFullname) and I push them into a list, then I get this list in a main script and I have to compare the keyboard input with each line of the list to get the info according to the user ID entered on the keyboard.
This is where I block, I can't isolate the value of the ID